# jquery dynamic control creation showing error

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-4.0

```
//control creation
function CreateTextBox(id, type, value, cls) {
$('<Input />', { id: id, type: type, name: 'textbox', value: value, "class": cls });
}

function CreatechkBox(id, type, cls) {
$('<Input />', { id: id, type: type, name: 'checkbox', value: value, "class": cls });
}

function CreateradioBox(id, type, cls) {
$("#radioholder").append($('<Input />').attr({ id: id, type: type, name: 'radiobutton' }).addClass(cls));
}

function CreateButton(id, type, value, cls) {
$("#btnholder").append($('<Input />').attr({ id: id, type: type, value: value }).addClass(cls));
}

function CreateDropDownlist(id, type, value, cls) {
$('<select />');
//$('<option />', { id: id, type: type, name: 'Label', value: value, "class": cls }).appendTo(s);
//$("#btnholder").append($('<Input />').attr({ id: id, type: type, value: value }).addClass(cls));
}

function CreateLabel(id, type, value, cls) {
$("<label>");
//$("#btnholder").append($('<Input />').attr({ id: id, type: type, value: value }).addClass(cls));
}

$(document).ready(function () {
//Ajax called .... get data and bind it into html
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:63945/Home/NewIndex",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:63945/Home/NewIndex", function (json) {
            var tr;
            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) { // for loop start
                tr = $('<tr/>');
                var component = '';
                switch (json[i].AttrControlType) {
                    case 'TextBox':
                        component = CreateTextBox('txtBox', 'text', 'text', 'form-control');
                        break;
                    case 'DropDownList':
                        component = CreateDropDownlist();
                        break;
                    case 'Label':
                        component = CreateLabel();
                        break;
                    default:
                        component = "Not Exist";

                }
                tr.append("<td>" + json[i].Pkid + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + json[i].FKid + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + json[i].AttrLabel + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + json[i].AttrColumn + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + component + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + json[i].AttrControlDatatype + "</td>");
                $('table').append(tr);

            } //for loop end
        });
    }
});
});
```

here i have created some functions which are dynamically creating components and under switch case i am checking condition that if component is label so component variable will take text feild, But i am not getting anything not the error also just "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this
create div in html give them id

```
 <div id="control"></div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    CreateTextBox("name", "text", "Enter your name", "form-control");    
});

function CreateTextBox(id, type, value, cls) {
    var str="<input type="+type+" id="+id+" value="+value+" class="+cls+" />"
    $("#control").html(str);
}
```

Comment: I dont want to create like this.......... i have a function that is returning me textbox in the form of object but i am not gettin how to convert it into html content

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `return` statements in your `Create` functions, like so:

```
function CreateTextBox(id, type, value, cls) {
    return $('<Input />', { id: id, type: type, name: 'textbox', value: value, "class": cls });
}
```

Then, you will also need to change the following line

```
tr.append("<td>" + component + "</td>");
```

into:

```
tr.append("<td>" + component[0].outerHTML + "</td>");
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using the "component" variable not inside scope hence its giving an error.
component should be globally declared or it should be used with in the scope.

Comment: seems like not understood , let me put it in this way. you have variable  declared inside the for loop but, u are using the variable outside for loop , so how it will work.

Comment: I can't see where is he using the `component` variable outside of the `for` loop.

Comment: @VinuthaN please check the edit...comments added for FOR LOOP

Comment: Can anyone tell whats the problem

Comment: function CreateLabel(id, type, value, cls) {
return $("<label>").text('Date:');
//$("#btnholder").append($('<Input />').attr({ id: id, type: type, value: value }).addClass(cls));
}

var test= CreateLabel();
alert(test.text());
}); with out using return it was giving as undefined . return and let me know it works or not

Comment: I posted an answer in case you didn't see.

Comment: Its the same. I dint noticed because page was not refreshed